# Problem with Soare's book on re sets.

Tags: computability, recursion

On page 16 of his "RE sets and degrees" he introduces the notion of a (Turing) computable function indexed by e with input x and output y taking fewer than s steps to complete, WHERE s has to be greater than e, x, and y.
Why must s be greater than e, x and y?
Surely most stopping programs will stop long before they perform e steps, since e is usually astronomical. But the real issue I have is with the x less than s requirement, since this means that s is going to grow arbitrarily large since x is arbitrarily large. How is this modelling Turing computability? There are masses of Turing machines that halt after a few steps regardless of the size of input. The function x-1 (for x not = 0) for instance "Delete the symbol you're on and move one space to the right, then stop".

Answer (score 4):

This is just a convention which makes some arguments simpler; it is harmless.

What do I mean by that? Well, one thing we can do is think of $s$ as the *maximum* of the running time defined in the usual way and $\max\{x, y, e\}$. Alternatively, you can show that there is a total increasing computable $f$ such that $\Phi_e$ and $\Phi_{f(e)}$ describe the same partial computable function but the running time of $\Phi_{f(e)}(x)$ is always greater than $f(e)$, $x$, or the output of $\Phi_{f(e)}(x)$ (just make your machine perform **lots** of pointless dithering). So we may just restrict our attention to machines of the form $\Phi_{f(e)}$ ($e\in\mathbb{N}$).

Keep in mind that we aren't really interested in questions of actual running time, it's just that for a lot of arguments we want to consider a number $s$ such that

- $\Phi_e(x)=y$ in $<s$ steps, and
- $s>e, x, y$.

We could give the least such $s$ a different name, say "fleen," but it's more intuitive to call it the "running time," even though that's slightly inaccurate.

---

Note that there definitely **are** occasions where this convention would *not* be harmless! In computability theory (as opposed to complexity theory), though, the questions we tend to ask are very robust: for instance, as long as we have an upper bound on how long a machine is going to take to halt, we're as happy as if we knew exactly how long it was going to take.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. The trouble is that as far as I can see the convention concerning s has at least one  consequence.

Comment: And that consequence is what, exactly?

Comment: Sorry I am having trouble with using these message boxes. The message was cut off yesterday. I am having difficulty with the question 4.7 on page 23 of Soare’s book.

We need to show that Fin is one one reducible to Cof.
We are given that 

phi (f(e)) = infinity if We,s+1 – We,s is not empty 
phi (f(e)) = 0 if it is empty.

Comment: When we come to show that ‘e doesn’t belong to Fin’ implies ‘f(e) doesn’t belong to Cof’  presumably we have the following chain of implications

e not in Fin 
e in Inf
We,s+1 – We,s not equal to empty set infinitely often because new numbers keep joining We
Phi(f(e)) = infinity infinitely often (so the complement of where it is defined has cardinality not finite.) 
f(e) not in Cof

Comment: But this argument only works if as s increases arbitrarily, We,s+1 – We,s is not equal to the empty set infinitely often.  By the convention about s being greater than x this is forced to be the case. x belongs to We for arbitrarily large x and hence We,s+1 – We,s is not equal to the empty set infinitely often. But this seems artificial. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting I did type it in Word and set it out nicely to start but evidently to no avail. These message boxes are evil.

Comment: "Seems artificial" is different from "is incorrect." Notice that we don't actually **need** the convention, it's just really useful. To avoid the convention, we could write the argument as follows (I'm using "$i$" for the map which in my answer I called "$f$," since you're using $f$ for something else): given an index $e$, let $i(e)$ be the corresponding "slow index" whose runtime is as Soare describes. Now from $i(e)$, I can define $f(i(e))$ as in your answer, and the biimplication $i(e)\in Fin\iff f(i(e))\in Cof$ holds as usual. So $f\circ i$ 1-reduces Fin to Cof. (cont'd)

Comment: Thankyou very much. I will look at your answer over the weekend.

Comment: Here's a more explicit convention-free argument that might make you happier (basically, just applying my general answer to this specific question): for an index $e$ and a natural number $k$, let $X_{e, k}$ be the set of $n<k$ such that $\varphi_e(n)$ halts in fewer than $k$ steps, and let $s_{e, k}=\vert X_{e, k}\vert$; note that $s_{e, k}$ is finite for every $e$ and $k$, and moreover the function $\theta(e, k)=s_{e, k}$ is total computable. Now for an index $e$ let $Y_e=\{k: \vert X_{e, k+1}\vert= \vert X_{e, k}\vert\}$. The passage from $e$ to $Y_e$ is computable (cont'd):

Comment: there's a computable total $f$ such that $W_{f(e)}=Y_e$ for every index $e$. Clearly $Y_e$ is cofinite iff $W_e$ is finite, so we're done.